# JMeter response time is high

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan written using JMeter & in that I have used Regular expression extractor to extract some value and pass it ON to other request in the test plan. I also used the CSV file to pick the value from sheet & used in my test plan.

Now the problem is that while running the script using JMeter, I am getting the high response time. When the JMeter is running the script, I tried to check the same site response manually & in that I was getting a very less response time.

I disabled the listeners & started the script in Non GUI mode but still the response time is on high side.

I need to justify the response time received from the JMeter to the client. Could someone please let me know what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: With how many users / threads do you run your test ? How much cpu does the jmeter process consume ? It is best when you post your test plan

Comment: I am testing with 50 VU. CPU consume does not go above 35%. How can I attach my files here ?

Comment: show your test plan structure and show some example of mismatch between browser timing and jmeter timing, are you sure you hit the server with browser during the test or before/after ?

Comment: @Naseem it is ok when you paste the jmx file as part of your question, click on edit to do that. But dont forget to format it as code. Before that you should create the smallest possible testplan that still has the issue. See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This shouldn't not happen if you are using same server for both Jmeter test and manuial browser test at the same time when load test is running. Response times should be approximately same. Did you clear your browser cache before testing? If not then clear it and then try.

Comment: @Marged Unfortunately I am unable to paste the image file due to my low reputation score. If you can share your email id, I'll share my test plan with you.

Comment: @Nachiket That's a good point. What I observed that when I hit the URL first time from the browser, it takes more time but when I hit the url second time, it comes fast.

Comment: :).  Is time after clearing cache and jmeter response time are nearly same?

Comment: Yes, after clearing cache, it's nearly same. I believe this is browser feature to save cache for quick loading of page next time but can this be achieve using jmeter ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the HTTP Cache Manager with Use Cache-Control/Expires header option which reduces the JMeter response time & nearly in sync with browser timing.